# How to use 14Hive in Sandbox?

Tags: sandbox-solution, mapped-folder

How can I use the 14Hive folder in my Visual Studio SandBox Solution ?

I want to use the Layout folder of that. And it gives me compile time error for LayoutsPageBase. And I can't access.

So is their any way sothat I can use aspx pages other than sample.aspx in my SandBox solution ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use the SharePoint root folder, nor any of its sub folders.

However, you can deploy an aspx file to the content database using a module. Look at the solution here: http://spkbase.codeplex.com

That solution also uses the SPUserCodeWebPart to run server-side code on those aspx pages.